# How to get values of all object fields in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I'm trying to make a JSON that will look like this:

```
[
    {
        "num_of_followers": 2,
        "name": "Math 140",
        "created_by": "aaa"
    }
]
```

The problem is I don't really understand how I can get a list of values for one particular database object (another words how can I get the whole row )

```
@csrf_exempt
def create_subject(request, subject):
    subject, created= Subjects.objects.get_or_create( 
        name=subject,
        user=request.user,
        created_by=request.user)
    list = []
    columns = [Subjects._meta.get_all_field_names()]
    row = ????????
    for value in row:
        record = dict(zip(columns,value))
        list.append(record)
    result = simplejson.dumps(list, indent=4)
    return HttpResponse(result)
```

Comment: are you looking for queryset .values() method? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

Comment: yes, exactly, I just found it, but unfortunately when I do this: row = Subjects.objects.get(id=3).values(), I'm getting error: 'Subjects' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: .get() returns an object instance, not queryset. In this example, Subjects.objects.filter(id=3) would work as intended

Comment: Can you post your answer,so I can close the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use .values() queryset method:

```
@csrf_exempt
def create_subject(request, subject):
    subject, created= Subjects.objects.get_or_create( 
        name=subject,
        user=request.user,
        created_by=request.user)

    return HttpResponse(
        simplejson.dumps(
            list(models.Subject.objects.filter(id=subject.id).values()), 
            indent=4
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 18):

If you are asking how to do that for ONE object, then you should use:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict


values = model_to_dict(the_object)
```

@Marat answer is nice and it works but it is for a `QuerySet`, not one object.

Comment: `model_to_dict` can also specify the fields we need in list format with `fields` parameter.  
`model_to_dict(instance=the_object, fields=['field_a', 'field_b', 'field_c'])`

Comment: Although `model_to_dict` may work, it looks like it is not documented, other than in the [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f9f9215d3e5500d9a8d0bec0936480ba34d42e88/django/forms/models.py#L94). Do you happen know of any docs? The [1.10 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/releases/1.10/#miscellaneous) mention it as part of the private API.

Comment: I did not see the documentation. I think they should do a property method on the model instead of a function. :)

Answer (score 1):

I struggled a bit with getting the file field to work properly. In the end this is what worked for me.

```
def queryset_object_values(object):
    fields = [field.name for field in list(type(object)._meta.fields)]
    field_values = [(field, getattr(object, field)) for field in fields]
    out = {}
    for field in field_values:
        if isinstance(field[1], FieldFile):
            out[field[0]] = field[1].url
        else:
            out[field[0]] = field[1]
    return out
```